# Any Cassandra operation require node to be down?

Tags: cassandra

Is there are any Cassandra related operations that would require node to be down (so this node is not available for read and write)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to alter the sstables which store data via the sstable2json or json2sstable tools the cluster shouldn't be running.

Answer (score 1):

One of such operations - rolling-upgrade from one version of Cassandra to another.  Here one need to disable thrift and gossip communications with other nodes and issue sstable upgrade command.